# My app still is not a tablet compatible

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet

I did many things to try and make my app compatible with tablets but nothing works. Here is what i tried:

- I have 5 folders drawable(ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi) and every folder contains the same images with different size.
- I have 3 layouts folders (small, medium, large) and everyone contain the same xmls
- I added this code and made anable the telephony which my app uses:

> ```
>   <uses-feature
>         android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
>         android:required="true" />
>     <uses-feature
>         android:name="android.hardware.camera"
>         android:required="false" />
>     <uses-feature
>         android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
>         android:required="false" />
> ```

- Also added this code for supported screens:

  ```
   <supports-screens
            android:anyDensity="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:resizeable="true"
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  ```
- I also have min sdk to 8.

What am really confused about is that i have an app already in store that doesnt use any of these and its min sdk is 8 and it says its compatible with tablets. It only has tha drawable folders, the layout folders and in this app i also have outside the /res folder, image folders like Images-ldpi, images-hdpi etc with the same images that i have in drawable folders.

By google what ive done to the first app should have worked by now but it doesnt.

My Manifest of the app that doesnt work on tablets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.0.6" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/olympialogo"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:logo="@drawable/olympialogo"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name="com.myapp.BootCompleted"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.myapp.BackgroundActivity" />

        <receiver android:name="com.myapp.SMSreceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.Splash"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="splashscreen" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.NumbersActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.CodesActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.SendCode"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.SettingsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.AllMessages"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.ButtonsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.OutputActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.AboutActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.Help"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.TechInfo"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the manifest of the app that is tablet compatible but has no settings at all in manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="lol.loltimers"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/lolicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TimersActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_timers"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.loltimers.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ThreeTimersActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_three_timers"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.loltimers.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please show your full manifest file.

Comment: If you want your app to be tablet-compatible, why do you require telephony?

Comment: because it uses messaging if they have 3-4g enabled

Comment: But it also uses wifi probably. I think the majority of tablets don't have telephone chip at all

Comment: no i dont use wifi. It interacts with sms thats its main purpose

Comment: `2 layouts folders (small, medium, large)` 2 or 3? `and everyone contain the same xmls` so, it's useless to have different layout folders, if the xmls are identical... just use `/res/layout`. I'd add a `/res/layout-land` folder, instead, for tablets. Also take in account that most tablets today still only connect through **WiFi**.

Comment: Its 3. Had a typo. I dont want it to have landscape. But y the other app that uses again the same layout folders works fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u need to make different folder in drawable

for tab you have to make as pet tabs conflagration

- drawable-large-mdpi //for 600x1024 mdpi tab
- drawable-large-hdpi // for hdpi tab
- drawable-large-ldpi //for  xhdpi tab

and then make change in dimension files

- values-sw600dp // for 7inch tab
- values-sw800dp // for 8 inch tab

if u have special layout requirement  then u need to make a different layout

- layout-large
- layout-xlarge

check this link 
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: This is actually really helpfull. So basically i should delete my layout(small,medium,large) folders, and leave only layout. And create 2 more folders the 
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml # For 7” tablets
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml # For 10” tablets and it should work right?

And delete the extra code i added in manifesT? or leave it there?

Comment: if you have special layout then u need layout folders otherwise only one layout folder and make different values folder for values and make different dimens it will sour work

Comment: ok lets explain with example...suppose u have a layout main.xml in layout folder..and you want to support to tab and your layout work complete in xhdpi..then u have to create different dimens and different values ..ex   
    values-sw600dp // for 7inch tab
    values-sw800dp // for 10 inch tab and u have a compont size 14 dp in xhdpi then make it 20 or 22 in dimes's of values600dp... and it automatic take from device wise

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

```
 <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
```

and check at runtime whether the device has messaging facility or not.